# Limit as $x\to \infty$ of a function given in integral form

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, definite-integrals

Consider $F(x) = \int_0^{x^2} \frac{t^2+1}{t^4+2t^2+4}dt$. I want to study
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} F(x), \quad \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{F(x)}{x}
$$

Ideas: First, we can observe than $f(t) = \frac{t^2+1}{t^4+2t^2+4}$ is a continuous function over $\mathbb{R}$, so $G(x) = \int_0^{x} \frac{t^2+1}{t^4+2t^2+4}dt $ is well defined, is continuous, differentiable and $F'=f$. Is clear that $F = G \circ g$, being $g(x) = x^2$, so $F'$ is also differentiable and we can easily compute its derivative using the Chain Rule.

If I find that $\lim_{x\to\infty} F(x) = \infty$, then I could apply L'Hôpital Rule and study the limit of $F'(x)$, which is $0$.

Can you help me with $\lim_{x\to\infty} F(x)$? I'm stuck with this part.

Comment: @Hyperon Thanks, I just fixed it.

Comment: I think that, since $F$ is continuous, you have that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}F(x)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{t^2+1}{t^4+2t^2+4}\,dt$$

Comment: @Davide but the improper integral $\int_0^{\infty} f$ is defined precisely as $\lim_{x\to \infty} \int_0^xf$, right? So I don't see I gain anything.

Comment: Yes, you have to compute the improper integral. In order to find the primitive, suggest using partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: Alternatively, you can compute the definite integral using Residue Calculus.

Comment: @TravisWillse I'd like to solve the problem using tools from a typical course of Calculus (real variable). Is there a way of solve the problem without computing primitives that only uses Real Analysis?

Comment: @Davide I thought the point of the exercise was to use the info provided by the FTC to avoid computation of primitives.

Comment: @ted If you are not interested in the value of the integral, then you have to study if the improper integral converges at $0$ and at $+\infty$. Notice that if $t=0$, then $f(0)=\frac{1}{4}$. On the other hand, if $t\rightarrow +\infty$, then $f(t)\sim\frac{1}{t^2}$ and we know that $$\int_{a}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{t^2}\,dt< +\infty$$ for all $a>0$.

Comment: I like the idea of using residue theorem since $x\to\infty$. Notice you can rewrite the integrand as

$$\frac{(t^2+1)(t^2-2)}{t^6-8}$$

Comment: @ted I don't see how you might. If all you care about is convergence, though, David's argument above shows that the limit $\lim_{x \to \infty}$ F(x) is finite, and since the integrand is positive, that limit is positive. We can also get the cheap estimate $\lim_{x \to \infty} F(x) < \int_0^\infty \frac{t^2 + 1}{(t^2 + 1)^2} \,dt = \int_0^\infty \frac{dt}{1 + t^2} = \frac\pi2$. In any case, once we know that $\lim_{x \to \infty}$ is finite, we get for free that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{F(x)}{x} = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, we're just computing
$$I := \int_0^\infty \frac{(t^2 + 1) \,dt}{t^4 + 2 t^2 + 4} .$$
Since the integrand is even,
$$2 I = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{(t^2 + 1) \,dt}{t^4 + 2 t^2 + 4} ,$$
and the latter integral can be evaluated using a standard residue calculus computation.

Let $\Gamma_R$ be the boundary of the half-disk $\{(x, y) \mid x^2 + y^2 \leq R, y \geq 0\}$, oriented anticlockwise. A standard estimate shows that the integral of $f(z) = \frac{z^2 + 1}{z^4 + 2 z^2 + 1}$ over the semicircular part of $\Gamma_R$ is $O(R^{-1})$. So, for large enough $R$,
$$2I = \oint_{\Gamma_R} f(z) \,dz = 2 \pi i \sum_{z^*} \operatorname{Res}\left(f(z); z^*\right),$$
where $z^*$ varies over the poles of $f(z)$ in the upper half-plane, namely,
$$z_\pm = \sqrt{2} \left(\pm \frac12 + \frac{\sqrt3}2 i\right) .$$
Computing the residues directly gives
$$\operatorname{Res}\left(f(z); z_\pm\right) = \lim_{z \to z_\pm} (z - z_\pm) f(z) = \frac{1}{4 \sqrt 2} \left(\pm\frac12 - \frac{\sqrt 3}{2} i\right) .$$
So,
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{(t^2 + 1) \,dt}{t^4 + 2 t^2 + 4} = \frac12 \cdot 2 \pi i \sum_{z_\pm} \operatorname{Res}(f(z); z_\pm) = \frac12 \cdot 2 \pi i \left(- \frac14\sqrt\frac32 i\right) = \boxed{\frac14\sqrt\frac32 \pi} .$$

Answer (score 1):

We have :$$ \frac{1+t^2}{t^4+2t^2+4}=\frac{1}{2(t^2+i\sqrt{3}+1)}+\frac{1}{2(t^2-i\sqrt{3}+1)}=\frac{1}{2\left({1+i\sqrt{3}}\right)\left({1+\frac{t^2}{1+i\sqrt{3}}}\right)}+\frac{1}{2\left({1-i\sqrt{3}}\right)\left({1+\frac{t^2}{1-i\sqrt{3}}}\right)}$$

Therfore:
$$F(x)=\int^{x^2}_0 \frac{1+t^2}{t^4+2t^2+4} dt = \frac{1}{2(1+i\sqrt{3})}I_1+\frac{1}{2(1-i\sqrt{3})}I_2$$

$$I_1=\int^{x^2}_0 \frac{1}{1+\frac{t^2}{1+i\sqrt{3}}}dt=\sqrt{1+i\sqrt{3}}\int^{\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+i\sqrt{3}}}}_0 \frac{1}{1+s^2}ds=\sqrt{1+i\sqrt{3}}\tan^{-1}\left({\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+i\sqrt{3}}}}\right)$$

and

$$I_2=\int^{x^2}_0 \frac{1}{1+\frac{t^2}{1-i\sqrt{3}}}dt=\sqrt{1-i\sqrt{3}}\int^{\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-i\sqrt{3}}}}_0 \frac{1}{1+s^2}ds=\sqrt{1-i\sqrt{3}}\tan^{-1}\left({\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-i\sqrt{3}}}}\right)$$

This implies that :
$$F(x)=\frac{\sqrt{1+i\sqrt{3}}}{2(1+i\sqrt{3})}\tan^{-1}\left({\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+i\sqrt{3}}}}\right)+\frac{\sqrt{1-i\sqrt{3}}}{2(1-i\sqrt{3})}\tan^{-1}\left({\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-i\sqrt{3}}}}\right)$$

Finnally:
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}F(x)=\frac{\pi}{4}\left({\frac{\sqrt{1+i\sqrt{3}}}{1+i\sqrt{3}}+\frac{\sqrt{1-i\sqrt{3}}}{1-i\sqrt{3}}}\right)=\frac{\pi\sqrt{6}}{8}$$